# How can I set google mail to not put php mail in spam folder?

Tags: gmail, phpmailer, spam

I am creating a site for me only that will run from my server. I would like it to send me emails using php which is setup, but the emails go into my spam folder in gmail. How can I change this in gmail, not php, to send these emails to my inbox? I have tried using mail() and phpmailer().

Here is the Php code that I have.

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();

$body = "email from server - testing.";
$from = "email@mysite.com";
$email = "myemail@gmail.com";

$mail->IsSMTP(); 
$mail->Host       = "localhost"; 
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;

$mail->SetFrom($from, "mysite.com");
$mail->AddReplyTo($from, "mysite.com");

$mail->Subject    = "emails";

$mail->MsgHTML($body);

$address = $email;
$mail->AddAddress($address, "me");

// $mail->Send();

if(!$mail->Send()) {
echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
echo "Message sent!";
}
```

Comment: Probably with sufficient re-training (clicking the _not spam_ buttons) it'll eventually learn that you like those mails.

Comment: Are you saying that I have to keep doing that until gmail recognizes the emails are not spam? I have pressed it once and it still goes into the spam folder.

Comment: it's at least one of the easiest ways you can influence their behavior. Perhaps setting up [dkim](http://www.dkim.org/) or [spf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) may help, but honestly, all Google's anti-spam measures are shrouded in secrecy and everything is just guessing...

Comment: Well, all it took was hitting that "Not Spam" button three times. It now shows up in my inbox. I don't know how to mark your suggestions as the answer. Maybe the moderaters do.

Comment: Because I don't _know_, I didn't bother giving it as an answer. Maybe I should have, that way you _could_ accept it or others could down vote it.. Anyway, Awalsh gave nearly the same answer, and he could use the points more than I, so feel free to mark his answer if you like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot see anything wrong with your code, since you seem to be setting the `From` correctly. I would however suggest that you check the actual headers received by GMail (`Show Original` under message options on the email/message) and check that the `From` header is correct. An incorrect sender is a common cause of issues like this.

As sarnold says above there is a degree of guess work involved, but I suggest you look at one or more of the following:

- Check/Setup SPF or DKIM for your domain
- Check/Setup a reverse dns record for the IP address used to send the emails
- Check if the IP address you are sending from is on any blacklists (contact your ISP if it is). [MXToolBox BlackList Checker](http://www.mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx) may be useful for checking multiple blacklists